# Sumbit button send information to a .txt file

Tags: html, forms

I have a form on my website but instead of opening an email page when clicking onto sumbit button. I'd like that the info is sent to a file either .txt, .docx or .xlsx.
Here is my form line codes!

```
<form name="input" method="post">
    Nom:
    <input type="text" name="nom" size="57" />
    <br />
    <br />

    Prénom:
    <input type="text" name="nom" size="53" />
    <br/>
    <br/>

    Vous êtes:
    <br/>
    <span class="list">
        <input type="radio" name="id" value="CEGEP" /> Étudiant au Cégep Édouard Montpetit <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="id" value="secondaire" /> Étudiant au Secondaire Jacques-Rousseau <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="id" value="heroux" /> Employé chez Heroux Devtech <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="id" value="autre" /> Aucune de ces réponses <br/>
    </span>
    <br/>

    Vous achetez le plus souvent:
    <br/>
    <span class="list">
        <input type="checkbox" name="achat" value="fleurs" /> Fleurs <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="achat" value="bonbon" /> Bonbons <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="achat" value="ballons" /> Ballons <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="achat" value="articles cadeaux" /> articles cadeaux <br/>
    </span>
    <br/>

    Commentaires
    <br/>
    <textarea name="commentaires" rows="5" cols="25"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
    <input type="reset" value="Effacer" />
</form>
```

Comment: Pick a programming language. Write a piece of software to accept the form data, format it and save it to a file. Then configure your webserver to run that program when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

add an action attribute to your form:

```
<form name="input" method="post" action="save.php">
```

and a name for your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer"  />
```

also change the name attribute of the second text field to *prenom*

create the file *save.php* in the same directory as the file in your form. add these lines to it:

```
<?php 
  if($_POST["submit"] === "Envoyer")
  {
    $fh = fopen("data.txt", "a");
    $content = "Nom:\t".$_POST["nom"]."\n";
    $content .= "Prénom:\t".$_POST["prenom"]."\n";
    $content .= "Vous êtes:\t".$_POST["id"]."\n";
    $content .= "Vous achetez le plus souvent:\t".$_POST["achat"]."\n\n";
    fwrite($fh, $content);
    fclose($fh); 

    header("Location: /url to your custom page displaying success/");       
  }
    header("Location: /redirect back to your form/"); 
?>
```

you may want to enhance it further, but this would be a way to do it.